# PyInstaller won't install, Python 3.6.0a4 and x64 Windows

Tags: python, windows, 64-bit, pyinstaller

I have said Python version (from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), and x64 Windows 10.
Every time I try to execute "pip install pyinstaller" it crashes with an error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\users\jskurski\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller)
Collecting pefile (from pyinstaller)
  Using cached pefile-2016.3.28.tar.gz
Collecting pypiwin32 (from pyinstaller)
  Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\jskurski\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-y9lsbd5f\pypiwin32\setup.py", line 121
        print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
                               ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jskurski\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-y9lsbd5f\pypiwin32\
```

So, for me it seems there is a version msmatch or something. Unofortunately, I can not figure it out myself.

Any suggestions?
Has anybody sucessfully used PyInstaller with latest 3.6 Python on Windows? Or maybe I should downgrade Python to older version?

edit: tested on another PC (same enviroment) and it was the same.

edit2: seems to work on 3.5.2 version, so it's probably a way to go, for now.

Comment: The error is a classic.  You are running python 2 code on Python 3.

Comment: @cdarke, well, so it seems, buuut... why it works with 3.5.2 version, then? Legacy broken in newest 3.6, or something? PyInstaller claims to work on 3.x, so I don't think it is that simple.

Comment: A `print` statement without parentheses will fail on 3.5.2, no question.  I didn't put this as an answer because, clearly, the 3.5.2 version is running different code.  Whether that is because it is running a different file/module, or whether the working version has code conditional on the version, I can't say.

Comment: 3.6 is not released until the end of the year, and Windows versions tend to lag behind, so you are being optimistic in using 3.6.  Maybe you didn't realise that the `a4` in the version number means alpha release 4?  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494/

Comment: I am aware, that this error I experienced was related to Python2 to Python3 differences, so I though that all Python3 was "doomed". But it worked with 3.5.2, latest stable; so for now I'm good.
In fact I was not aware of the alpha release.

Comment: it isn't particularly clear on the download site that 3.6 is an alpha release.  Its one of those things that you'll never do again!

Comment: Yeah, well, I simply went for the latest release, I'm definitely no expert in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case is closed for me, as I downgraded to stable 3.5.2. Probably some inconsistency in that alpha release, which caused this. I just wanted to write a simple GUI Windows program, so I will not investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

pyinstaller needs pypiwin32 module.
when pip tries to install it, it shows an error because there is no pypiwin32 for python3.6

Answer (score 1):

You have to install manually pywin32 according to your version of python. The following link you can download.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221/

Once installed pywin32 with your right version of python. Pyinstaller must be installed

Answer (score 0):

As cdarke pointed out, you are running python 2 code on Python 3.

Try this instead:

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

Comment: Case is closed for me, as I downgraded to stable 3.5.2. Probably some inconsistency in that alpha release, which caused this.
I just wanted to write a simple GUI Windows program, so I will not investigate further.