# Pyinstaller isn't working

Tags: pyinstaller

Whenever I try to run pyinstaller.py with my script it outputs a bunch of code and I have no idea what it means. All I'm trying to do is turn my python file into an executable but it isn't working. It looks like it's working until it says Traceback after 100 and then it shows a whole bunch of file locations.

```
C:\Users\Smith 1>python C:/py/pyinstaller.py C:/py/Calculator.py
84 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
84 INFO: Python: 3.6.0
84 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
84 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Smith 1\Calculator.spec
84 INFO: UPX is not available.
100 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\py', 'C:\\Users\\Smith 1']
100 INFO: checking Analysis
100 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
100 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
100 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
100 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/py/pyinstaller.py", line 15, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 317, in assemble
    excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
    graph.import_hook(m)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1509, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1661, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 209, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2077, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2167, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2585, in _scan_code
    module, module_code_object, is_scanning_imports=False)
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2831, in _scan_bytecode
    global_attr_name = get_operation_arg_name()
  File "C:\Users\Smith 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2731, in get_operation_arg_name
    return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyInstaller won't install, Python 3.6.0a4 and x64 Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315160/pyinstaller-wont-install-python-3-6-0a4-and-x64-windows)

Comment: Last i checked, Pyinstaller was still working on python 3.6 support.

Comment: have you tried `auto-py-to-exe`?